# Jquery width() overflow Safari issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, width

Wrapping a table under a narrow div with `overflow:auto`. Under chrome, IE, FF, the width is over 200 which is expected. But in safari the with is 100.

Jquery width() docs didn't mention this? https://api.jquery.com/width/

The code pen, open console and scroll to see the log: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adZxrd

In case it fails, the details below.

---

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>aaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.inner {
    width:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.outer').scroll(function(){
    console.log($('.table').width())
});
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution, at least for me. Theres `max-width: 100%` on the table (seems to be default), weird issue but setting it to `none` fixed it.

This question solved it for me: [Javascript: Calculation of width in Safari/iOS for elements overflowing their containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888858/javascript-calculation-of-width-in-safari-ios-for-elements-overflowing-their-co)

Working (updated) codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRjOoy?editors=1111